# Spinning wheel shows before view appears

Tags: ios, swift

I'm presenting a view modally. In presented view I'm starting activity indicator before calling API to fetch data. The problem is that this activity indicator shows up before destination view is fully presented.

I know that moving the calling API inside `viewWillAppear` solves the problem but I don't want to call it there.

Is there any way to fix it except moving it into `viewWillAppear` ?

```
class ListVC: UIViewController {

    func detailsTapped() {
        let destVC = instantiate(DetailsViewController)
        destVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        destVC.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
        self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.startAnimating()
        //.. fetch API
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a little delay(preferably 0.3) to the startAnimating method

self.perform(#selector(startAnimating), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)

The delay could be unnoticed and you might achieve what you want.

Comment: Not a clean code. Data maybe fetched before spinning wheel shows up which will defeat the purpose of having indicator.